# How can i use the Facebook login?

Tags: android, facebook

Somebody know how can i make the facebook login like this picture? Or where i find the documentation.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything? Which trouble are you facing?

Comment: i already tried the last version, but the behavior is different.